# How to improve this hover effect?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hover on an element and I want the hovering(color effect) to cover entire cell. Currently it covers only half. This is how it looks currently. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/KXqvRE).

[image: current image]

And this is how I want it to look.

[image: required]

Below is the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftSideNav1">
    <div class="leftSideNav1__lists">
        <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i><br />Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="leftSideNav1__lists">
        <a href=""><i class="material-icons">pause</i><br>YouTubers</a>
    </div>
    <div class="leftSideNav1__lists">
        <a href=""><i class="material-icons">assignment</i><br>Campaigns</a>
    </div>
    <div class="leftSideNav1__lists">
        <a href=""><i class="material-icons">message</i><br>Messages</a>
    </div>
    <div class="leftSideNav1__lists">
        <a href=""><i class="material-icons">pause</i><br>Videos</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper .leftSideNav1 {    
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/14;
    background-color: #37474f;  
}

.wrapper .leftSideNav1__lists { 
    padding: 15px;      
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper .leftSideNav1__lists a{    
    color: #9e9e9e;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper a:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: #fff;
    display: block; 
    box-sizing: border-box;     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the padding from **.wrapper .leftSideNav1__lists** so the CSS will be like that :

```
.wrapper .leftSideNav1__lists {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

add the padding to the **a** tag and make it **inline-block** like this :

```
.wrapper .leftSideNav1__lists a {
    color: #9e9e9e;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I missed display:inline-block part. It worked. Thank you lot!

Comment: welcome, the idea is to make the hover element take the whole space, so no padding/margin around it and instead put it all inside it ;)

Comment: Hey how do i also remove the hovering misbehaviour on leftsidenav2. check the link and hover. you will see it. https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/KXqvRE

Comment: you mean they they jump ?

Comment: Yes. Other elements move due to hovering

Comment: the issue is due to the fact that you change them to **display:block** on hover. So you may also put them display:block initially and remove the **br** tag between them (useless when you add display block)

Comment: It didn't work as expected. When i try to hover it still is breaking. It is pushing other elements

Comment: you need to add it here **.leftSideNav2__lists-sections a** the display block

Comment: Just amazing! Thanks a lot!